# MacOSX SSD potential performance issues (TRIM) with VM guest OSes

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, performance, virtual-machine, ssd, trim

So, back in September of last year, I was *pretty* sure I was going to buy an SSD for my MacBook Pro (2009); here's my [previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/191583/upgrade-macbook-pro-2008-to-ssd). I decided to hold off and wait for Intel and OCZ to release their newer SSDs and my patience has paid off.

Now, I'm at the purchasing point of buying the new SSD, however it's unclear to me whether MacOSX 10.6 has issues with TRIM and (more importantly) will running a Windows 7 VM will have any impact on the SSDs performance *over time*.

Some posts that I've read specifically point out the degrading performance in OSX as it doesn't support TRIM. Other (Mac) posts say they've had no issues with degrading performance.

So which is it and what's *really* going on? Will running Snow Leopard (10.6) without TRIM support with a Windows 7 VM be okay or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll be fine. The VM performance won't suffer since the data is ultimately written to the disk by OS X and not the VM itself.
10.7 will support TRIM by default. For 10.6, you can download [TRIM Enabler](http://groths.org/zeus/TRIMEnabler.zip) from [Oskar Groth's blog](http://www.groths.org/?p=308).

Comment: [Related blog post](http://www.groths.org/?p=308).

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeet. I didn't even find anything about TRIM enabler until you mentioned it. Thanks!